# How to delete google scripts ClockTrigger after it executes

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have some code which needs to execute one function based on an hourly trigger, then another function exactly one hour after the first one. Like this:

```
function main() {
  firstFunction();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('secondFunction')
  .timeBased()
  .after(60 * 60 * 1000) // 60 mins * 60 s * 1000 ms
  .create();
}
```

This is working fine. I just noticed though that the triggers build up in "my triggers" of the google apps script console. Is there any way to delete the trigger after execution?

Comment: I always check to see if there are triggers with same function name before creating new ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After execution,

- get trigger id from [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events)
- [delete the trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#deleteTrigger(Trigger)) associated with the id:

```
function secondFunction(e){
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(
    ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().find(
      trigger => trigger.getUniqueId() === e.triggerUid
    )
  );
}
```