# How to Automatically End Triggers in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

Is there a way to end a trigger after a month or two in Google App Script?
Like for example, I want the trigger to occur on a daily basis just for one month and discontinue after the end of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Check the date in trigger function daily and [if current date is greater than first day of next month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/) and if so, [delete the trigger using trigger unique id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61383586)

Answer (score 0):

#### Delete all Triggers

```
function stopAllTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(t => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t));
}
```